# Sharepoint Survey - Add Indexed Columns

Tags: survey

I have a sharepoint survey that is has a large amount of questions.  The survey gets used quite alot around 6000 entries with about 20-30 questions.

The problem is its a bit clunky and heavy.  Is there anyway to index the columns on the suveys tables?

I noticed you can do this with other lists - the options seem to differ for Sharepoints Surveys however.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

In "Survey Settings" click on "Metadata navigation settings"

Modifying the key filters here may help improve performance depending on the filters you are using.

There is also two radio buttons below for Automatic/Manual indexing of columns. To the left of that there is a "Indexed Columns" link which will take you to the page for managing column indexes.

Also this [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813%28v=office.14%29.aspx) has a good overview of managing large lists